# How do I download Anaconda packages without "installing" them?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

See title.  I'd like to download a compressed package from the Anaconda repository for later installation.  How would I use the conda tool to do that?

Answer (score 13):

Use the `--download-only` flag.

```
$ conda install --help
usage: conda install [-h] [--revision REVISION] [-y] [--dry-run] [-f]
                     [--file FILE] [--no-deps] [--only-deps] [-m] [-C]

...

  --download-only       Solve an environment and ensure package caches are
                        populated, but exit prior to unlinking and linking
                        packages into the prefix.

...
```

Comment: This flag is NOT unavailable in conda 4.3.34.

Comment: How can I find the downloaded packages?

Comment: @ziyuang did you find answer?

Comment: @misha In my case it is the `pkgs` folder under the Anaconda/Miniconda root; maybe it will be different if not in the base environment

Comment: @ziyuang It is indeed in the pkgs folder. 
Note: all the downloaded/installed packages by conda are placed in the pkgs folder under the Anaconda/Miniconda root; even those downloaded from a non-base conda env.

Comment: I get: `All requested packages already installed.` - where are my wheels?